# How to export images from IBM Rational Rhapsody diagrams

Tags: uml, rhapsody

Im using IBM Rational Rhapsody 7.6 for UML modeling.
Iv'e created class diagrams, use cases, sequence diagrams and i want to export it to some kind of image or PDF or something, anything that is viewable in a nice way will do.

I found the export to report under "Tools" but then you get a rich text file with a super odd format and the class diagrams will be cut up in the middle to fit the A4 pages.

So how to export to an image from IBM Rational Rhapsody, UML modeling.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to export a single diagram, right click on diagram and select "Export Diagram Image" and there you go.
If you want to have a model with many diagrams exported at once, you can try the HTML output via Reporter Plus (built into Rhapsody), or for more features you can try Rational Publishing Engine (additional licenses might be required).

Comment: How can I customize the quality of the image being exported?

Comment: you can just select the format of image being exported (right now as of rhapsody developer 8.2.1 there are available: bitmap, jpeg, tiff and emf) , and then you can postprocess it.

Comment: I was looking for image processing which will be embedded in the application itself like Visio have.
I would still like to know even though I have moved completely to Visio for current Project.

Comment: rhapsody doesn't provide embedded image processing in the way Visio provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can export diagrams to PDF by installing a PDF writer such as CutePDF (http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp)

Then select File\Print Diagrams from the menu in Rhapsody and print chosen diagrams to PDF